# How to save Adam optimizer parameters in Keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, adam

Adam algorithm in Keras:

> Initialize `m_0` as 1st-moment vector,
>
> Initialize `v_0`as 2nd-moment vector,
>
> The update rule for `theta` with gradient `g`:
>
> `lr_t = learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta_2^t) / (1 - beta_1^t)`
>
> `m_t = beta_1 * m_{t-1} + (1 - beta_1) * g_t`
>
> `v_t = beta_2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta_2) * g^2`
>
> `theta_t = theta_{t-1} - lr_t * m_t / (sqrt{v_t} + epsilon)`

**I want to know how to save `m_t` and `v_t` at each step `t` in Keras.**